# What is the formal structure to write a patent request?

Tags: law, writing, written-description, programming-tools

I need to write a patent request, is there any formal structure to follow?
 My patent aimed on a programming script for a new security method.

Comment: Do you meant you want to apply for a patent? If so, in what country? Most countries have specific forms and such, but (of course) a US patent application isn't going to work very well in, say, Japan (or vice versa).

Comment: Yes, I'm in United Arab Emirates, Middle east.

Comment: Where you plan to file is the issue, not where you are personally located. I assume you plan to file in the U.S. for a U.S. patent?

Comment: @ George White: Actually I want to file it in UAE, but is it different when I apply it here not in US directly? Aren't US and UAE in Same organization?

Comment: @mran - yes the US and the UAE are both members of the WIPO and both are parties to the Paris Convnetion and the PCT (Patent Cooperation Treaty). However every coutry has its own formats, forms and rules for filing. One big commonality can be reached by using a PCT application rather than a UAE application. PCT forms/formatting rules are universal. From  a quick look at the WIPO site UAE residents file their PCT applications with the International Bureau in Geneva. See PCT Applicant's Guide http://www.wipo.int/pct/guide/en/gdvol1/pdf/gdvol1.pdf. You will probably benefit from local help.